# LibGDX: Miscalculated polygon collision

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx

These 2 polygons are not colliding, though this method returns true:

```
Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(
            new float[]{
                        100.0f, 750.0f, 
                        200.0f, 750.0f, 
                        100.0f, 150.0f, 
                        200.0f, 150.0f
                        },
            new float[]{
                        77.0f, 695.0f, 
                        91.0f, 695.0f, 
                        84.0f, 681.0f
                        },
            null);
```

Am I using it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first polygon is not convex, swapping vertex 3 and 4 solved the problem

Comment: Then please mark you answer as final (the green check icon).

Comment: Is there any documentation that mentions the specific order that you need to define your verticies in?

Comment: I need to wait 2 days until I can mark my own answer as the correct one.

Comment: @ashes999, you need to enter in the same order you would if you were drawing it with a pen, but of course this doesn't guarantee it's convex